# How to save and add new fits header in fits file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, astropy, pyfits

i have a fits file and i want to add a new header to the fits file.

I've actually added a new fits header but it didn't save it. How to save and add new fits header?

Codes here:

```
from astropy.io import fits
hdul = fits.open('example.fits.gz')[0]

hdul.header.append('GAIN')
hdul.header['GAIN'] = 0.12
hdul.header.comments['GAIN']="e-/ADU"

print(hdul.header)
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Just as a small notational clarification: What you seem to be trying to do is not to add a new *header* but rather to add a new "card", in FITS terminology, which is a keyword, value, and optional comment.  Equivalently, for short, you can say you're adding a new keyword.  The "header" is the entire collection of cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` opens the FITS file in read-only mode by default.  If you want to modify the file in place you need to open it with `mode='update'`.  Also, appending the new header can be done in a single line (as documented in [`Header.append`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/headers.html#astropy.io.fits.Header.append) like:

```
with open('example.fits', mode='update') as hdul:
    hdul[0].header.append(('GAIN', 0.12, 'e-/ADU'))
```

Or, if you already have a FITS file open in read-only mode, you can write the modified file out to a *new* file using the writeto method as mentioned [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html#save-file-changes).

One caveat I noticed in your original example is you were opening a gzipped FITS file.  I'm not actually sure off the top of my head if that can be modified in `'update'` mode, in which case you'll definitely need to write to a new file.  I believe it *does* work, so try it, but I forget how well tested that is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the 50 reputation points to comment on @Iguananaut's answer, so I'll leave my comment here: Make sure it is `fits.open()`. Otherwise, it will give you the following error `ValueError: invalid mode: 'update'`.

Using @Iguananaut's example, it should be:

```
with fits.open('example.fits', mode='update') as hdul:
    hdul[0].header.append(('GAIN', 0.12, 'e-/ADU'))
```

Also, using `append()` will append the same 'new' card for every time you run the code. To prevent this, I suggest a minor adjustment. It will not just add the new card you want, but it will also update that same card if you run the code multiple times, avoiding card multiples.

```
with fits.open('example.fits', mode='update') as hdul:
    hdr = hdul[0].header
    hdr['GAIN'] = (0.12, 'e-/ADU')
```